# get my data from ajax POST request returns none

Tags: django-views, ajaxform

I print out the data and it says it's none. Also when I `console.log` the data on the js side before it's sent off it's perfectly intact. This is a Django project locally hosted on my PC.

Here's the js:

```
function sendList(maList,name) {
    //event.preventDefault();
    var liste = maList;
    var namee= name;
    var csrftoken = $('[input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val();
    console.log(csrftoken);
    console.log(maList);
    console.log(name);
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/newCoords/",
            headers: {
                'X-CSRFToken':csrftoken,
                
            },
            contentType:'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType:'text',
            data: JSON.stringify({
                "pointName": namee,
                "fieldPoints": liste,
                //csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken
            }),
            sucess: function() {
                console.log(bruh);
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                console.log(error);
                }
        });
}
```

Then here's the Python view file

```
def newCoords(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        pointName = request.POST.get('pointName')
        fieldPoints= request.POST.get('fieldPoints')
        print(pointName)
        print(fieldPoints)
        point = points(pointName=pointName,fieldPoints=fieldPoints)
        point.save()
        print("alrighty then mate")
        
        return HttpResponse("200")
    else:
        print('well drats')
        return HttpResponse("how messed up is messed up")
```

I've tried messing with the model but I ended up just saving null and none fields to my db. I also tried `json.dumps` the data afterwards into the model on the view side rather than the js side to no avail. I feel like I'm missing something. I'm still pretty green to this.

Answer (score 0):

In Django you can get request data like this...

#### Views.py

```
def CreditSaveView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        creditform = CreditForm(request.POST)
        if creditform.is_valid():
            amt = request.POST['amt']
            tag = request.POST['tag']
            crs = request.POST['csrfmiddlewaretoken']
            CreditModel(amt=amt,tag=tag).save()
            return JsonResponse({'status':'done'})
```

#### urls.py

```
path('creditsave/',CreditSaveView),
```

#### Ajax code

```
document.getElementById("creditbtn").addEventListener("click", function() {
    let id_amt = document.getElementById('id_amt').value;
    let id_tag = document.getElementById('id_tag').value;
    let crs = document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')[0].value
    my_data = {csrfmiddlewaretoken:crs,amt:id_amt, tag:id_tag};

    console.log(my_data)

    $.ajax({
      url: "/creditsave/",
      method: "POST",
      data: my_data,
      success: function (data){
        if (data.status == 'done'){
          document.getElementsByTagName('form')[1].reset()        
        }
      }
    });
  });
```